# Loop through a column and lock the row if any value exist

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to vba and looking for sample code that able to loop through column and lock the row if the value exist in cell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions for when you're coding:

1. Use [option explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) so you don't have unexpected behavior with undefined variables
2. Define your variables with the closest corresponding type (for example `cl` is a `Range` in your code, you defined it as an object which may work, but you looses intellisense among other features)
3. Always indent your code (see [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) a free tool that help you with data)
4. With the previous one, just a matter of taste, but defining each variable in a separate line, will help you keep your code organized
5. Try to separate your logic defining variables and the reusing them
6. Avoid using select unless it's strictly necessary

Review and customize the code so it fits your needs.

You can see what's happening in the code by pressing `F8` and executing it line by line.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim targetRow As Range

    Dim sheetPassword As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim lockedResult As Boolean

    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    sheetPassword = "Test"

    ' Remove protection
    targetSheet.Unprotect Password:=sheetPassword

    ' >>>>>Remove cells protection to whole sheet<<<<<<<
    targetSheet.Cells.locked = False

    'Find last row in column B (that's what the 2 means after Count,)
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set the evaluated range
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    For Each targetRow In targetRange.Cells
        ' Check the first cell (that's what the 1 means after (,)
        Select Case targetRow.Cells(, 1).Value
        Case "TOP LEVEL", "No", "Maybe so" ' All of these cases are OR as they are separated by a comma
            lockedResult = True
        Case "Test", vbNullString ' All of these cases are OR as they are separated by a comma
            lockedResult = False
        Case Else
            lockedResult = False
        End Select

        targetRow.EntireRow.locked = lockedResult

    Next targetRow

    targetSheet.Protect Password:=sheetPassword

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: the above code lock the whole page even the `lockedResult=False` condition fulfilled. I try to modify the codes but couldn't get it right

Comment: The whole page is locked because that's the default setting for all cells in a sheet. You need the code to do the opposite if you want the whole sheet to be unlocked, except some cells / rows. I've updated the code look for this line: ' >>>>>Remove cells protection to whole sheet<<<<<<<

Comment: Thanks, never thought of unlock the whole sheet at initial 1st. But somehow this code doesn't loop and lock the 1st Case only

Comment: Please explain what you mean that it doesn't loop and lock the 1st case only.

Comment: This line `Case "Test", vbNullString`is telling Excel to unlock them but remember that is evaluating only cells in `A` column

Comment: Sorry, i messed up with my modified version of coding. Restart everything then now it work perfectly. Thanks so much for guidance!!!

Comment: If it works, remember to mark the answer with the check mark at the left of it so others may find it. ...Don't understand why somebody downvoted it. Anyways...

Comment: Sure will do. Upvote it and check the mark as answer done!!

Answer (score -1):

```
 Sub test()
Dim cl As Object, strCells As String, lastRow As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Unprotect password:="Test" 
lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
strCells = "B1:B" & lastRow 
    For Each cl In Range(strCells)
        Select Case cl.Value
            Case "TOP LEVEL", "No", "Maybe so" 
                cl.EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Locked = True
            Case "Test" 
                cl.EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Locked = False 
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next cl
.Protect 'password:="Test"
End With
End Sub
```

I add `EntireRow.Select` then next line `Selection.Locked = True/False. Now everything worked perfectly.

Comment: But those empty cell suppose to be locked=False but somehow is still lock. Even i define `Case ""` is `locked=False`. Anyone can help?